# Fetch the password is send to email using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, soap, sendmail

I have to fetch the password from MySQL database. That password is send to user valid email in Java using JDBC. How can I implement this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
public class Checkemail
{
    public String authentication( String Email ) {

        String retrievedUserName = "";
        String retrievedPassword = "";
        String status = "";

        try {
            Class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart-432pro", "root", "" );
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement( "SELECT * FROM xcart_customers WHERE email = '" + Email + "'" );
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            while( result.next() ) {
                retrievedUserName = result.getString( "email" );
                retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
            }

            if( retrievedUserName.equals( Email ) ) {
                status = "Valid Email";
            }

            else {
                status = "Invalid Email!!!";
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

Here I have checked the email is valid or invalid successfully.

How can I write the code for fetching the password and these password is send to email function?

**EDIT:**

Now i have changed the code like below:

```
    if(retrievedUserName.equals(Email)){
      status = "Valid Email";
      Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
         props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
         props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxxx@gmail.com","xxxx");
                        }
                    });

                    try {

                                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("krishnaveni.veeman@mercuryminds.com"));
                            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                    InternetAddress.parse(Email));
                            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                        message.setText("Dear Friends This is your fassword," +
                                    retrievedPassword);

                    Transport.send(message);

                        System.out.println("Done");

                        } catch (MessagingException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                }
                               }
                                  else{
                         status = "Invalid Email!!!";
                          }

                                }
                            catch(Exception e){
                               e.printStackTrace();
                                   }
                             return status;

                              }


                                }
```

Here i have mentioned my gmail username and password on my code openly.

```
       Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("xxxxx@gmail.com","xxxx");
                        }
                    });
```

I have send mail w/o mention gmail username and password.please help me.how can i develop these.

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Comment: Simple: 1) make sure the password is stored in the database, in your xcart_customers table, 2) fetch it the same way as you did e-mail: `retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");`, 3) e-mail it to your user (you can use the JavaMail API.  For this to work, you must store the e-mail in clear text, and e-mail it in clear text.  Security?  We don't need no stinkin' security ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 yes i can done above 2 steps.i can't develop 3rd step.so please explain detailly

Comment: So it's a `JavaMail` problem.  What have you tried?  I did a quick Google for "java mail send email" and got [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) which looks interesting

Comment: @MadProgrammer how can i call the javamail code in my code.how can i send that fetching password via email.the above tutorial is explained simple email send feature.but i have to send password via email.how can i implement these.am a beginers.please help me

Comment: Sooo, the tutorial site shows you to an email, but you don't seem to be able to figure out how to put your simple string into the message, is that what you're telling me...

Comment: @MadProgrammer i can't able to put these send email code to my code.here my email is valid means the fetching password is send to email.For Eg:how can i set the my fetching password on message.setText("This is actual message");
 these message field.also where  i have to call SendEmail class on my class.

Comment: `javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25` means that the SMTP host you've provided is invalid/not responding.  You need to point it to a valid server, try the one from your email program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **use valid host**.

This may help you..

```
      String host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Host for Gmail
      Properties props = System.getProperties();
      props.setProperty("mail.user", from);
      props.setProperty("mail.password", retrievedPassword);
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
```